# Diagonalization of the generalized 1-particle density matrix

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a complex separable Hilbert space and $\mathscr{F}$ be the corresponding fermionic Fock space generated by $\mathscr{H}$. Let $\rho: \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{F}) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded linear functional on all bounded operators of $\mathscr{F}$ with $\rho(I)=1$ and $\rho(A^*)=\rho(A)^*$, and define the 1-particle density matrix (1-pdm) by the unique bounded self-adjoint $\Gamma: \mathscr{H}\oplus \mathscr{H}^* \to \mathscr{H}\oplus \mathscr{H}^*$ such that

$$
\langle x|\Gamma y\rangle = \rho([c^*(y_1)+c(y_2)][c(x_1)+c^*(x_2)])
$$

where $x=x_1 \oplus \bar{x}_2$ and $y=y_1 \oplus \bar{y}_2$ (I use the notation $\bar{x} (\cdot) = \langle x|\cdot\rangle$) and $c,c^*$ are the annihilation/creation operators.

In references V. Bach (Generalized Hartree-Fock theory and the Hubbard model)**[Theorem 2.3]** and J.P Solovej (Many Body Quantum Mechanics)**[9.6 Lemma and 9.9 Theorem]**, the authors claim that (under suitable conditions) $\Gamma$ is diagonalizable by a Bogoliubov transform $W:\mathscr{H}\oplus \mathscr{H}^* \to \mathscr{H}\oplus \mathscr{H}^*$ so that $W^* \Gamma W = \operatorname{diag}{(\lambda_1,...,1-\lambda_1,...)}$. The main idea of the proof is that $\Gamma$ is diagonalizable by an orthonormal basis, and that if $x\oplus \bar{y}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $y\oplus \bar{x}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1-\lambda$. The proof is fine when $\lambda\ne 1/2$, since the 2 eigenvectors are orthonormal to each other. However, if $\lambda=1/2$, then things become a little more difficult. J.P Solove solves this in the case where the eigenspace of $\lambda =1/2$ is even-dimensional, but as far as I know, I can't understand why would it be.

**Question**. Is there something I'm forgetting? If not, is there a way or are there references that complete the proof?

**EDIT**. It's clear that if $\mathscr{H}$ is finite-dim, we see that the eigenspace of $\lambda=1/2$ is even-dim (due to the fact that the orthogonal complement is even-dim and $\mathscr{H}\oplus \mathscr{H}$ is even-dim). However what happens if $\dim \mathscr{H} =\aleph_0$ (infinitely countable)

Comment: Could you point out where Solovej explicitly considers the case $\lambda=1/2$?

Comment: @popoolmica He proves this in the 9.6 lemma and applies it in equation (73).